# Merging the content of methods

Tags: java

I have the following methods:

```
public ArrayList<Weapon> getDbWeapons()
{
    ArrayList<Weapon> dbWeapons = new ArrayList<>();       

    EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();
    TypedQuery<Weapon> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Weapon i", Weapon.class);
    dbWeapons = new ArrayList<Weapon>(query.getResultList());
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return dbWeapons;
}

public ArrayList<Armor> getDbArmors()
{
    ArrayList<Armor> dbArmors = new ArrayList<>();

    EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();
    TypedQuery<Armor> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Armor i", Armor.class);
    dbArmors = new ArrayList<Armor>(query.getResultList());
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return dbArmors;
}

public ArrayList<Potion> getDbPotions()
{
    ArrayList<Potion> dbPotions = new ArrayList<>();
    EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();
    TypedQuery<Potion> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Potion i", Potion.class);
    dbPotions = new ArrayList<Potion>(query.getResultList());
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return dbPotions;
```

And my question is - how do I first call the methods into another method (in the same class), merge their content to one ArrayList, and then return it?

Thanks for answer!

Class Item there (interface for the new method):

```
package com.dke.ps.Items;

/**
 * General class for an item containing common information sutch as id, name,
 * description, path to an icon, price and type of an item.
 * @author valecvit
 * @author koresmi1
 */
public abstract class Item
{
    /**
     * Unique id of an item.
     */
    public int itemid;
    /**
     * Name of an item.
     */
    public String name;
    /**
     * Description of an item.
     */
    public String description;
    /**
     * Relative path to item image.
     */
    public String icon;
    /**
     * Type of an item.
     */
    public int type;
    /**
     * Price of an item.
     */
    public int price;

}
```

My Table.Weapon class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dke.ps.Tables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author michal
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "weapon")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByItemid", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.itemid = :itemid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByName", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByDescription", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.description = :description")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByIcon", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.icon = :icon")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByType", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.type = :type")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByPower", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.power = :power")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Weapon.findByPrice", query = "SELECT w FROM Weapon w WHERE w.price = :price")})
public class Weapon implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "itemid")
    private Integer itemid;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "icon")
    private String icon;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type;
    @Column(name = "power")
    private Integer power;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemid", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private ItemsId itemsId;

    public Weapon() {
    }

    public Weapon(Integer itemid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public Integer getItemid() {
        return itemid;
    }

    public void setItemid(Integer itemid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Integer getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(Integer power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public ItemsId getItemsId() {
        return itemsId;
    }

    public void setItemsId(ItemsId itemsId) {
        this.itemsId = itemsId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (itemid != null ? itemid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Weapon)) {
            return false;
        }
        Weapon other = (Weapon) object;
        if ((this.itemid == null && other.itemid != null) || (this.itemid != null && !this.itemid.equals(other.itemid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.dke.ps.Tables.Weapon[ itemid=" + itemid + " ]";
    }

}
```

This is second class Weapon in package com.dke.ps.Items

```
package com.dke.ps.Items;

/**
 * Class for a weapon.
 * @author valecvit
 * @author koresmi1
 */
public class Weapon extends Item
{
    /**
     * Attack power of the weapon.
     */
    public int power;

    /**
     * Initializes new weapon.
     * @param id            unique item id
     * @param name          name of item
     * @param description   description of item
     * @param icon          path to item image
     * @param price         price of item
     * @param type          type of item
     * @param power         power of item
     */
    public Weapon(int id, String name, String description, String icon, int price, int type, int power)
    {
        this.itemid = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.price = price;
        this.type = type;
        this.power = power;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe a class `Player` that has each of those `List`(s)?

Comment: I just updated my original post

Comment: Do Weapon, Armor, and Potion all extend Item?

Comment: class Items.Item is abstract so I cant call something like that: Item myNewItem = new Item(bla bla bla);

Comment: Yes, all these classes extend Item

Comment: You should return List, not ArrayList.  Stick to the interface type.

Comment: The first thing to look into: get rid of the code duplication. Those two methods you are showing are almost identical. Extract the common parts and then have probably two small wrappers calling that unified method.

Comment: Can you please show me how exactly it has been done to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Just create `List<Item> getAllItems()` method and add all the items to a single list, for example for `Weapon` query:

```
public List<Item> getAllItems() {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    // Database-related code
    items.addAll(new ArrayList<Weapon>(query.getResultList())); 
    // Same for 2 remaining Item subclasses 
    return items;
}
```

Probably there may be no need to wrap `getResultList()` in an `ArrayList`, check that in the documentation of `getResultList()`.

Also, you may do all 3 database queries in a single transaction.

Comment: I don't think you want to create a `new ArrayList` in each of the three methods, do you?  It's not clear from your answer how and where you're supposed to create the new list.

Comment: There is error in your solution - ')' expected, cannot find symbol, symbol: variable query, location: class Server, Reduntant type of arguments in new expression (use diamond operator instead)

Comment: There was a missing bracket. You should also add relevant code for handling DB queries (exactly the same as in your solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that calls your existing methods:

```
public List<Item> getAllItems()
{
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.addAll(this.getDbWeapons());
    items.addAll(this.getDbArmors());
    items.addAll(this.getDbPotions());

    return items;
}
```

Comment: That way you have to have 3 separate transactions and create 3 different list when you actually need 1.

Comment: @ΔλЛ I don't think we need to concern ourselves with optimizing the transactions at this point. Why not reuse the code OP already has, which does it in 3 separate transactions. Also, to the calling code it's just one List. How is that different than your code which will also add lists to the returned list?

Comment: If i use your solution, it shows to me this exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dke.ps.Tables.Weapon cannot be cast to com.dke.ps.Items.Item (updated my original post)

Comment: @Aaka Your Weapon class does not extend Item. When I asked you in the comment, you said  Weapon, Armor, and Potion all extend Item.

Comment: I have two classes Weapons - the first is in package com.dke.ps.Items. (updated original post) and the second one is in package com.dke.ps.Tables - This class was created as an entity (I have the same table in the database. I showed it in original post)